# Make div fill up the rest of the space

Tags: css, html

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_h_/FR5Ud/22/)

I would like to have multiple divs with margins and below them one that fills up the rest of the space provided by the fixed size parent div.

EDIT: I am sorry, I should have mentioned that the container divs size is fixed and should not change at all.

EDIT2: [SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/p_h_/FR5Ud/32/).
I had tried overflow: hidden but missunderstood it and put it on on the child element and not the parent.

Comment: Be more specific please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is you want http://jsfiddle.net/FR5Ud/33/

Comment: nice one for adding the three divs at the top, however you don't need to float the fill-up region, and some one should probably call the OP on why they are floating left the container - they may not need to :)

Comment: @pebbl - You are correct, only when the top part is equally divided. see this http://jsfiddle.net/FR5Ud/31/ Hope you understand why I used `float:left`

Comment: Yep, no worries I understand. If it were me I would user `overflow:hidden` - this causes less complications with surrounding elements and is unlikely to cause a problem as users generally don't want content breaking outside their elements.

Comment: @pebbl `overflow:hidden` for `#toFillUp`? Would you mind replicate this on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: sure, just replace the `float:left` with `overflow:hidden` - http://jsfiddle.net/bdLn6/ - it will have the same affect as using float to force the fill up region down below the floated divs above. My example shows the same 2x divs at the top as your example. I just tend to have a thing against `float:left` due to the amount of site's I've taken over responsibility for that overuse float left and it causes normal layout to behave unexpectedly. It's totally down to preference though :)

Comment: Wow it's a good workaround. Thanks Pebbl. This is a new thought for me. I'll update my answer with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height` so that your basic look of the page remains the same and it increases based on the content

```
#container {
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 300px; height
    border-color: violet;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
}

#content {
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 100px; height:auto
}

#toFillUp {
    background-color: red;
    /* that's what it should end up looking like.
    However, what if the size of #content changes?
    What if there are more content divs before that?
    What if those have margins? */
    min-height: 200px; height:auto
}​
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/FR5Ud/25/

Comment: nice point with the min-height, but you have a superfluous/empty height floating around in your css :) and there has been no introduction of the three divs (with margins) at the top.